# Mahout Item Similarity Output Empty

Tags: mahout, collaborative-filtering

I'm using Mahout's ItemSimilarityJob to compute similarity of items with an input .csv file that looks like this:

`user_id(numbers only), song_id(numbers only), listens(numbers only)`

When I run the ItemSimilarityJob with these parameters

`$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.similarity.item.ItemSimilarityJob --input inputcsv/ --output outputcsv --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORRELATION --tempDir tempcsv --booleanData true`

I get a blank part-r-00000 file inside music/csvoutput directory. There are many files inside music/csvtemp however. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, your input is where you think it is, or you're not indicating where you think you are. Usually the --input is a fully qualified path. Check and try that. Or your data is so small that no similarities can be computed.

Comment: Hi @sean-owen. Thanks for replying. I ran the job again; this time without the `booleanData true` and it created a large part-r-00000 text file. Maybe when booleanData is set to true it needs a four-tuple `user-id`, `item-id`, `value`, and the optional `preferences`.

Also, do you know how I can read the similarityMatrix file formed in the temp folder. There are a lot of files inside the temp folder that I'm not sure how to read. Thanks again.

Comment: No, boolean data means it ignores rating -- all are treated as "1". This is completely incompatible with the Pearson correlation, since it will make all similarities undefined. You would use log-likelihood instead. But then you need not include your third column at all.

Comment: Oh yes, I realized I ran it again with loglikelihood (and without booleanData true) and it worked. Thanks for your time, Sean. I just saw your profile. A BIG thank you also for your contributions to Mahout. Although I'm still exploring, it's a wonderful tool for ML-newbies like me. :)

Comment: Hi @sean-owen. Could you tell me if I would like to consider rating as well (i.e. 3-tuple csv user, item, rating), which of the predefined similarity measures can I use (I believe loglikelihood is out of the question as it considers 2-tuples). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

hope my experience and answer helps others, really could have saved me some precious time.
You would also want the check the value of the --threshold parameter.
Setting it too high (even 0.01) causes Mahout to filter data and eventually 
generate empty files.
In my case it was my random generated data that caused this.

Answer (score 0):

`mahout org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.similarity.item.ItemSimilarityJob -i intro.csv --output outputcsv --similarityClassname SIMILARITY_PEARSON_CORRELATION -m 3  --tempDir tempcsv --threshold 0.7  --booleanData`

this will work use it